# Spring cloud sleuth doesn't work with log4j2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

When i add sleuth dependency in a spring boot project that uses log4j2 for logging, i get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/FilterRegistrationBean
```

Does sleuth work only with logback and it support log4j2 also ?

Comment: It might be some version mismatch. Similar issue : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9027

Comment: My question is: does sleuth support log4j2 or logbavk only ?

Answer (score 0):

the error you are getting is for FilterRegistrationBean, it maybe due to the version mismatch of spring-cloud and spring-boot. There is a issue with compatibility of Spring-boot version 2.x.x and Spring-cloud version 1.x.x

refer to this:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/836#issuecomment-376846920